# how to export some specific points of a regular grid in python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, split, geometry

I have coordinate points (`x` and `y`) and want to rearange them. All points are stored in a list. List has several arrays and arrays have unique `x` values:

```
sp_arr=[np.array([[1., 8.]]), np.array([[2., 8.], [2., 9.]]), \
        np.array([[3., 8.], [3., 9.], [3., 10.]]),\
        np.array([[4., 8.], [4., 9.], [4., 10.]]),\
        np.array([[5., 9.], [5., 10.]]), np.array([[6., 9.], [6., 10.]]),\
        np.array([[7., 10.]]), np.array([[8., 10.]])]
```

If the length of array is less than `1`, I do nothing. I uploaded a fig to visualize what I want. Figure has three rectangle and I want to rearange my points based on them. Change of length of arrays is the most important siganl for me. It changes from second to third array. So, I need to extract all the rows of shorter (second) array and `2` (length of shorter array) rows of third one. I extract first `2` rows of third array because the mean of `y` value in third (longer) array is higher than shorter. If it was less, I would export last `2` rows.

Rectangle 2 contains the arrays that their length is maximum.

From fourth to fifth array, length changes (rectangle 3).Again I keep all rows of shorter arrays (fifth and sixth) and `2` (length of shorter arrays) rows of longer one. Mean of `y` is shorter arrays is higher, so I keep last two rows of longer array. Finally, I want the following result:

```
surfs=[np.array([[2., 8.], [2., 9.], [3., 8.], [3., 9.]]), \ # first rectangle
       np.array([[3., 8.], [3., 9.], [3., 10.], [4., 8.], [4., 9.], [4., 10.]]),\# second rectangle
       np.array([[4., 9.], [4., 10.], [5., 9.], [5., 10.], [6., 9.], [6., 10.]]) # last rectangle]
```

I tried the following code but it was not successful:

```
surfs=[]
for i in range(len(sp_ar)-1):
    if 1 < len(sp_ar[i]):
        if sp_ar[i][-1][1] != sp_ar[i+1][-1][1] or sp_ar[i][0][1] != sp_ar[i+1][0][1]:
            if np.mean (sp_ar[i][:,1]) < np.mean (sp_ar[i+1][:,1]):
                surfs.append([sp_ar[i],sp_ar[i+1][0:len(sp_ar[i])]])
            if np.mean (sp_ar[i][:,1]) > np.mean (sp_ar[i+1][:,1]):
                surfs.append([sp_ar[i], sp_ar[i+1][-len(sp_ar[i]):]])
```

In advance, I do appreciate any help.
[image]

Comment: For anyone seeing this question, there are [more details in the comments to the follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67500954/1431750).

Comment: dear @trincot, Can you please take a look at this question. I appreciate your help in advance.