# How to rearrange numpy arrays stored in a list based on the lengths of the arrays

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, split

I have a list of numpy arrays and want to rearrange it based on the length of each array. This is my list:

```
nums=[np.array([[2.], [3.]]), np.array([[8.], [7.], [1.]]),\
      np.array([[1.], [0.], [5.]]), np.array([[8.], [9.]]), np.array([[7.], [6.]])]
```

It is important when the length of arrays change. The list of lengthes is:

```
lns=[2, 3, 3, 2, 2]
```

Based on `lns`, length changes from first to second array. First array is shorter and I want all rows of it. I want `2` (length of shorter array) rows of longer (second) one. In this case the average of shorter array (`2.5`) is less than the average of longer (`5.3`), so I extarct the first `2` rows of the longer array. I want both second and third arrays because their lengths are maximum. From the third to the fourth the length changes. Again I want all rows of shorter and `2` (length of shorter, i.e. fourth). But, the average of shorter (`8.5`) is higher than longer (`2.`). So, I need the last `2` rows of the longer one. Finally, I want to rearrange my list to get the following one:

```
final=[np.array([[2.], [3.], [8.], [7.]]),\ # all rows of first and first 2 rows of second
       np.array([[8.], [7.], [1.], [1.], [0.], [5.]]),\
       np.array([[0.], [5.], [8.], [9.], [7.], [6.]])]# last 2 rows of third and all rows of next short arrays
```

I do appreciate any help to do what I want in python.

Comment: **1.** Show what you have tried. **2.** Your logic is a bit over-complicated. The first array was length 2 but in the `final` it's length 4. **3.** Why are the 2nd and 3rd arrays merged into one array in `final`? Because of same length? **4.** Taking the either the first 2 elements (length of shorter _neighbour_) or taking the last 2 elements is based on the average of the two arrays? Or is it based on which array comes first? **5.** You've used numpy arrays but not tagged numpy. Are you actually using numpy arrays or Python arrays or regular Python lists?

Comment: **6.** You're using single-element arrays in `nums` and `final`, like `[[8.], [7.], [1.]]` instead of `[8., 7., 1.]`. What's the reason for that? **7.** You're also using a _list of arrays of single-element-arrays_ instead of _an array of arrays of single-element-arrays_. Why? **8.** Is this just a programming exercise or is there an underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Dear @aneroid, Firstly, I do appreciate your time. **1.** About my try, I really coulnot tackle this problem at all, sorry I am not thatt much expert in programming and python. **2.** Length of first array in `final` is increased because it is created by merging first array and two rows of second array of `nums`. **3.** Because their lengths is quals to the maximum length. **4.** I always use shorter neighbour. **5.** Numpy arrays. **6.** In reality my rows have three columns and I only copied one column to make it easier. **7.**  My array in reality is not single. It has three columns.

Comment: Dear @aneroid, **8.** I am solving a problem. I am cleaning my data to import them into a python library.

Comment: Dear @aneroid, hours ago I opened another question which can be another version of my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67499831/how-to-export-some-specific-points-of-a-regular-grid-in-python

Comment: Okay, so based on the other question, you're given an arbitrary list of points (in 2D space, in the other question, but then actually 3D space) which _may_ represent shapes. And you want to create intersecting shapes in 2D/3D; and disregard points which are not able to form closed polygons (so lines are not okay). Having that description is better. Also, the 1D version doesn't help because it's got irrelevant factors - like the taking the average. If two adjoining shapes had very different sizes and were not connected, doing that "average" thing doesn't help in any way.

Comment: PS. You don't need to say Dear each time. Zero-times/once is more than enough :-)

Comment: I'd say wait a while before opening more questions. If after 48 hrs there are no satisfactory answers, you can [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) on the other question. I _could_ take a crack at answering this one but it doesn't actually solve the problem you're having on the original question.

Comment: @aneroid, in reality my points are 3d (`x`,`y` and `z`). But I only rearrange them based on `x` and `y`.

Comment: @aneroid, I do appreciate your help. But, both problems look the same, isn't it? In this question I only work with lengthes rather than values.

Comment: You're _framing_ both problems similarly but they're not the same. For example, on the other one, it's clear that you want to create adjacent shapes without overlaps. That can actually be solved in a completely separate way if you said _**"given a list of 2D points, how do I create multiple squares/rectangles/closed-shapes that touch each other without overlapping"**_ - see? That has nothing to do with the number of elements in the array or taking averages, etc. Btw, we call this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/193893). The drawing on the other is good though.

Comment: @aneroid, I believe both are the same. I the example with fig, I am using all the points but here I use only lengths of each array. In the fig I also had the overlap. Rectangles have similar points. First rectangle is created by all rows of a short arrays and first two rows of the longer one.

Comment: **9.** Another inconsistency in the logic: for array 3 (len 3) and array 4 (len 2), the result should be `0 5 8 9` and the last item in the result should be `8 9 7 6`. Why are these merged into one as `0 5 8 9 7 6` at the end? They should be separate. What's the logic to merge them all for the 3rd, 4th and 5th arrays but not for the 1st, 2nd & 3rd arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, I'm using the [`pairwise()` recipe from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) to get two successive elements at a time, instead of using indexes:

```py
import itertools

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

2. I created a helper function `first_or_last()` which returns a [`slice` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) which can be [used on a numpy array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html), and is applied to the larger of the two neighbouring arrays<sup>3</sup> being compared. Which slice needs to be applied depends on the average/mean value, as per the logic you described above. You can reduce it to a two-line function if you want, I've used the longer version for comments/explanation.

```py
def first_or_last(smaller, larger):
    """return a slice object for either the first-n items or
    the last-n items of the larger array
    """
    size = len(smaller)
    if np.mean(smaller) < np.mean(larger):
        # take first-`size` elements
        return slice(None, size)
    # take last-`size` elements
    return slice(-size, None)  # don't skip the extra None, needed for axes
    # or just
    # return slice(None, size) if np.mean(smaller) < np.mean(larger) else slice(-size, None)
```

3 . The code which does the re-arranging:

```py
nums = [np.array([[2.], [3.]]), np.array([[8.], [7.], [1.]]),
        np.array([[1.], [0.], [5.]]), np.array([[8.], [9.]]),
        np.array([[7.], [6.]])]

final = []
for ar1, ar2 in pairwise(nums):
    l1, l2 = len(ar1), len(ar2)
    if l1 == l2:  # same length
        final.append(np.append(ar1, ar2, axis=0))
        continue
    # different lengths
    arrs = (ar1, ar2[first_or_last(ar1, ar2)]) if l1 < l2 else (ar1[first_or_last(ar2, ar1)], ar2)
    final.append(np.append(*arrs, axis=0))
```

Value of `final`:

```py
[array([[2.], [3.], [8.], [7.]]),
 array([[8.], [7.], [1.], [1.], [0.], [5.]]),
 array([[0.], [5.], [8.], [9.]]),
 array([[8.], [9.], [7.], [6.]])]
```

---

Notes:

1. The output of this differs from what you have as `final`. See [item #9 in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67500954/how-to-rearrange-numpy-arrays-stored-in-a-list-based-on-the-lengths-of-the-array#comment119328206_67500954), as I don't see the rule/logic that would make the result have 3 items and not 4.

   > **9.** Another inconsistency in the logic: for array 3 (len 3) and array 4 (len 2), the result should be `0 5 8 9` and the last item in the result should be `8 9 7 6`. Why are these merged into one as `0 5 8 9 7 6` at the end? They should be separate. What's the logic to merge them all for the 3rd, 4th and 5th arrays but not for the 1st, 2nd & 3rd arrays?
2. This solution won't give errors for [your previous/original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67499831/1431750) but it also doesn't seem to be the right output - even though it does follow the same rules.
3. NumPy array slicing returns a view on the orignal array, not a copy.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But, lets think for example the length of all arrays is 3. Then, I want only one array because all of them have the maximum length. Or for example lets consider the length of first array is also 3, then I only want to have two arrays. Can you to somehow converge this solution toward the problem I mentioned in another post? thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Again, I don't see what the underlying logic would be to apply to that. You could add that "if the next array is the same length as the last, then append it to the previous pair". Suggest you add a `last_arr` which compares to `ar1` and /or `ar2` and checks/flags if `ar2` was sliced in the previous iteration, etc. And if so, then append it to the previous result rather than as a new row: `final[-1] = np.append(final[-1], ar1, axis=0)` (and for `ar2` if necessary). Without the slice check, [see this modification on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/CjTT2gQQ).